# "Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop" error when useState hook is used

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, infinite

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const Counter = () =>{

    let [counter,setCounter] = useState(0);

    return(
       <div className='counter-box'>
            <span>{counter}</span>
            <button onClick={setCounter(counter++)}></button>
       </div>
    )
}
export default Counter;
```

I'm using functional component here. Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I recommend to go through react documentation with example. It exactly has your example explained. React hooks tutorial - introducing hooks https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.
Here the `onClick` function is getting executed when it's rendered instead of user click event.

Solution 1:

```
import {useState} from 'react';

const Counter = () =>{

    let [counter,setCounter] = useState(0);

    return(
       <div className='counter-box'>
            <span>{counter}</span>
            <button onClick={e => setCounter(counter+1)}></button>
       </div>
    )
}
export default Counter;
```

Instead of executing the code, we pass a function reference(anonymous arrow function) to the `onClick` event.